# Angular clear input when setting model to undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an input where I am using `ngModelChange` to parse input like so

```
<input [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="value = parse($event)" [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" />
```

Where the `parse` function either returns a value, or `undefined` if the input is invalid.

If the input is valid, then changes to an invalid value, assigning `undefined` clears the input as desired.

If the value is already `undefined` and an invalid input is entered, the parse function returns `undefined` again, but the input is not cleared.

How can I force the view to update in this second case, or tackle this problem a different way.

Comment: sorry, so what is happening currently?  and what do you want it to do?

Comment: maybe we can put together a stackblitz, let me know if you want me to try to set one up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following when an invalid value is entered:

- Set `value` to the value entered in the `input` element
- Force an update of the view by calling `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges`
- Set `value` to `undefined`
- Let Angular update the view on change detection

This can be done by setting a different handler for the `ngModelChange` event:

```
<input [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="setValue($event)" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}" />
```

The `ChangeDetectorRef` class is injected in the constructor, and the event handler `setValue` is defined as follows:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

setValue(val: string) {
  const result = this.parse(val); // Get final value
  if (!result) {                  // If final value is invalid
    this.value = val;             // Set temporary value
    this.cd.detectChanges();      // Force view update
  }
  this.value = result;            // Set final value
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hiavft) for a demo.